# How to call a function of a contract with unknown source code?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Let's say I want to interact with a contract but I don't know the ABI of this contract. Via the UI I know which functions are called (by inspecting the transaction).

How do I call these functions in a solidity?

Answer (score 2):

You create an interface and you can call it (provided you know the address of the contract).

```
contract contractX {
  function methodY(uint param1) public pure returns (int);
}

contract KnownContract {
  address unknownContractAddress = '0x0123...';

  function callFriendContract(uint param1) public {
     uint res = contractX(unknownContractAddress).methodY(param1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, but doesn't this need you to know the ABI? How does the compiler know at what (code) address it has to `JUMP` to?

Comment: No, you don't need to know the ABI for that.

Comment: You do not need the ABI if you know the interface. The answer from @mirg assumes that you know the functions. The interface doesn't need to define the implementation of the functions is enough to know the name and what parameters take in and what parameters return.

Comment: You need the ABI to call it from web3 not from Solidity

Comment: I see, but the compiler needs to know some kind of order here to call the right address of this function? If I have two functions which have a boolean as input and return a boolean, how do I call function 1 and how do I call function 2?

Comment: You need to know the function name to do so. methodY is not a generic name. It should be the method name of the contract that you're trying to invoke.